# How can I get data from a SQL server passed with correct column type

Tags: sql-server, r

I am reading data from a SQL server. The SQL server data base has tables with person-specific information from various sources (medical centers, HMOs, and state registries). There is a participant identifier in each table named PID. The construction of PID very much depends on the data source, with some some data sources having PID values which are entirely composed of numeric values and other data sources having PID values which are mixed alphanumeric.

In order to produce a combined sources analysis, I need to construct a data frame consisting of tables from the various sources. PID is stored on the SQL server as str(20). I would like to get read the data into R, keeping the type specified on the SQL server. I am using the RODBC package with odbcConnect to declare my ODBC connection to the SQL server and sqlFetch to read the data as follows:

```
> library("RODBC")
> ch <- odbcConnect("PROSPRdfm", uid="........", pwd="........")
> 
> # Read h3_crc_ppt data from SQL server
> crc_ppt <- sqlFetch(ch, "h3_crc_ppt")
```

I then attach crc_ppt and test whether PID is character:

```
> attach(crc_ppt)
> is.character(PID)
[1] FALSE
```

For this particular table, all of the PIDs were numeric.  But other tables have PIDs which are alphanumeric. Is there an argument that can be passed to sqlFetch that would force R to honor the variable typing specified on the SQL server?

Comment: Try `str(crc_ppt)` to see what your query returns. It probably is a data.frame.

Comment: Yes, crc_ppt is of type data.frame.  That is why I attached crc_ppt before querying whether the column PID was character.

Answer (score 2):

Try `sqlFetch(ch, "h3_crc_ppt", as.is = TRUE)`

From `?sqlQuery` (`sqlFetch`wraps it)

> Where possible sqlGetResults transfers data in binary form: this happens for columns of (ODBC) SQL types double, real, integer and smallint, and for binary SQL types (which are transferred as lists of raw vectors, given class "ODBC_binary"). All other SQL data types are converted to character strings by the ODBC interface.
>
> This paragraph applies only to SQL data types which are returned by ODBC as character vectors. If when creating the connection (see odbcConnect) DBMSencoding was set to a non-empty value, the character strings are re-encoded. Then if as.is is true for a column, it is returned as a character vector. Otherwise (where detected) date, datetime and timestamp values are converted to the "Date" or "POSIXct" class. (Some drivers seem to confuse times with dates, so times may get converted too. Also, some DBMSs (e.g. Oracle's) idea of date is a date-time.) Remaining cases are converted by R using type.convert. When character data are to be converted to numeric data, the setting of options("dec") is used to map the character used by the ODBC driver in setting decimal points—this is set to a locale-specific value when RODBC is initialized if it is not already set.

Comment: When I add as.is = TRUE, EVERY column is returned as character. That doesn't seem to be the answer.

Comment: Your answer lies in the documentation.

"Then if as.is is true for a column, it is returned as a character vector."

Make `as.is = c(FALSE, FALSE, ...TRUE)`, based on the index of your 
 PID column.

Comment: OK, that works.  But pardon my saying that this is extremely poor behavior.  I am just familiarizing myself with R, trying to move from SAS.  The database has MANY tables, some with hundreds of variables.  There are a lot more variables whose representation should be character than just the one variable mentioned. (PID is a key variable in a relational DBMS.)  SAS handles reading the tables and accepts the type specified on the SQL server.  Having to manually construct a lengthy logical vector is ripe for incorrect specification.

Comment: I don't understand. Isn't the problem solely with PID being a mix of numeric and alphanumeric characters? Only the PID column needs to be `as.is = TRUE` and the rest can be false, which should be an easy logical to construct using `rep`. 

From my understanding the documentation suggests SQL strings should be read in R as strings even when `as.is = FALSE`, so there may be something else fishy going on.

Comment: No.  I only introduced PID as character because it is a key variable in a RDBMS and to illustrate my problem.  There are a number of other ID variables which are key variables for other tables.  There are also ZIP and FIPS codes plus other variables that should be character.  R wants to convert everything that is a string to a factor.  That really slows down data handling.  Having to specify position by position which columns should be read with as.is=TRUE is really tedious.  There is no justification I can think of for R not honoring the SQL DB type specification.